# Is there a word or phrase that could fully describe this sphere made of flags?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image: s]

Is there a word or phrase that could fully describe this sphere made of flags? I don't think there's a word for this, but I don't even know if I can describe it properly into words.

A sphere whose lattice is made up of rectangular shaped flags?

Comment: As with all such word requests. Please indicate either that "a word for this exists in my language, but the translation in a bilingual dictionary is not acceptable for some reason", or explain why you think a word should exist in English, but not in your language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word you could use is **mosaic**:

> A sphere made from a mosaic of rectangular flags.

NOAD defines *mosaic* as:

> **mosaic** (*noun*) a picture or pattern produced by arranging together small colored pieces of hard material, such as stone, tile, or glass

While one could argue that your image is not comprised of stone or tile, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mosaic) goes a little further and adds:

> **mosaic** (*noun*) 
>   1 : a surface decoration made by inlaying small pieces of variously colored material to form pictures or patterns
>   2 : a picture or design made in mosaic
>   3 : something resembling a mosaic

[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/mosaic) has this definition:

> **mosaic** (*noun*) made of small pieces inlaid to form a pattern; also, resembling such inlaid work.

In other words, if it looks like it could be made as a mosaic, you can call it a mosaic, even if it’s merely an image instead of something made from inlaid tile or glass.